# How to extract properties from json format data?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to learn node.js in doing so I came across a problem.
Here is the code:

```
exports.postLogIn = (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ name: req.body.username, emailid: req.body.emailid })
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.length) {
        console.log("value of result: " + result);
        res.render("shop", { logged: true, name: req.body.username });
      } else {
        res.render("login", { notlogged: true });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

When I do
`console.log(result)`

I get output as:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61bab8123a555f52d3f190e3"),
  name: 'Patrik',
  emailid: 'patrik@gmail',
  __v: 0
}
```

I want to extract the value of `_id` but when I `console.log(result._id)` I get result as `undefined`

Please guide me on how to extract the value of _id

Comment: Could you give more context? How do you get the result?

Comment: @FivePlyPaper I have added the code, please let me know if more clarity is required

Comment: does it return it just as an object or is it double nested? Example `[{_id:  new ObjectId("61bab8123a555f52d3f190e3")}]`

Comment: `result` is array I believe? So you may use `result[0]._id`, `result.map(el => el._id)` etc

Comment: yes, it is coming as [{....... }]. I faced this problem because when placed some text before result like ``console.log("value:"+ result)`` the output in the terminal appeared as ``value:{.........}`` but when i tried  ``console.log(result)`` i receive the result as ``[{.........}]``. btw my code has started to work by doing ``result[0]._id`` . thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to just grab the first item you could do as Xeelley said above and just reference the `result[0]._id`

If there are multiple results you could do an `Object.keys` with a `.forEach`

```
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(result[key]._id);
});
```

This loops through each nested result and then allows you to access their objects. Could be useful if need to grab more than one in the future!